# SyntaxError: -> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: reactjs, json, error-handling, fetch, node-oracledb

I am trying to fetch from an oracle database inside a docker container a SQL query and then show the response as a dropdown inside the web interface.
This is the get method from the server side:

```
app.get('/api/getDropdownOptions', (req, res) => {
    oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig, (err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connected to Oracle Database');

        const sql = 'SELECT nume FROM JUDETE';
        connection.execute(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch dropdown options' });
            } else {
                console.log(result.rows);
                const dropdownOptions = result.rows.map((row) => ({ nume: row[0] }));
                console.log(typeof dropdownOptions)
                console.log(dropdownOptions)
                
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send(dropdownOptions);
            }
        });

        connection.close((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
            console.log('Disconnected from Oracle Database');
        });
    });
});
```

This is the react page :

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import './DatePersonale.scss';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { faExclamationCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import FormContext from './FormContext';

export default function DatePersonale() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { formData, updateFormData } = useContext(FormContext);
  const [dropdownOptions, setDropdownOptions] = useState([]);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({
    cnp: '',
    nume: '',
    prenume: '',
    email: '',
    telefon: '',
    judet: '',
    adresa: '',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the dropdown options from the server
    fetchDropdownOptions();
  }, []);

  const fetchDropdownOptions = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/getDropdownOptions');
      console.log(typeof response, response);
      //console.log(await response.text())
      const data = await response.json(); 
      console.log(data); 
      setDropdownOptions(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching dropdown options:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    updateFormData(id, value);
    console.log(formData);
    setFormErrors((prevErrors) => ({
      ...prevErrors,
      [id]: '',
    }));
  };

  const inputFields = [
    { id: 'cnp', label: 'CNP' },
    { id: 'nume', label: 'Nume' },
    { id: 'prenume', label: 'Prenume' },
    { id: 'email', label: 'Adresă email' },
    { id: 'judet', label: 'Județ' },
    { id: 'telefon', label: 'Telefon' },
    { id: 'adresa', label: 'Adresă domiciliu' },
  ];

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errors = {};

    inputFields.forEach((field) => {
      if (formData[field.id].trim() === '') {
        errors[field.id] = 'Va rugăm completați câmpul';
      }
    });

    setFormErrors(errors);
    console.log(Object.keys(errors).length);
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
      navigate('/creare-cont/date-cont');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main-section-header">
        <button className="deactivated">
          1 <span>Date personale</span>
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => navigate('/creare-cont/date-cont')}>2</button>
        <button onClick={() => navigate('/creare-cont/date-card')}>3</button>
      </div>
      <div className="main-section-content">
        <form className="form-creare-cont" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="part">
            {inputFields.slice(0, 4).map((field) => (
              <div className="form-element" key={field.id}>
                <label htmlFor={field.id}>
                  <span className='label-text'>
                    {field.label} *
                    {formErrors[field.id] && (
                      <p className="error">
                        <i>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExclamationCircle} />
                        </i>
                        {formErrors[field.id]}
                      </p>
                    )}
                  </span>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id={field.id}
                    value={formData[field.id]}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    required
                  />
                </label>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="part">
            <div className="form-element">
              <label htmlFor="judet">
                <span className="label-text">
                  Județ *
                  {formErrors.judet && (
                    <p className="error">
                      <i>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExclamationCircle} />
                      </i>
                      {formErrors.judet}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </span>
                <select
                  id="judet"
                  value={formData.judet}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  required
                >
                  <option value="">Selectați județul</option>
                  {dropdownOptions.map((option, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={option.nume}>
                      {option.nume}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </label>
            </div>
            {inputFields.slice(6).map((field) => (
              <div className="form-element" key={field.id}>
                <label htmlFor={field.id}>
                  <span className='label-text'>
                    {field.label} *
                    {formErrors[field.id] && (
                      <p className="error">
                        <i>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExclamationCircle} />
                        </i>
                        {formErrors[field.id]}
                      </p>
                    )}
                  </span>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id={field.id}
                    value={formData[field.id]}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    required
                  />
                </label>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="bottom">
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Înainte
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
When I am calling that api in POSTMAN it return the good JSON format :

```
[
    {
        "nume": "Bucuresti"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Alba"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Arad"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Arges"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Bacau"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Bihor"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Bistrita-Nasaud"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Botosani"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Braila"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Brasov"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Buzau"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Calarasi"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Caras-Severin"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Cluj"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Constanta"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Covasna"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Dambovita"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Dolj"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Galati"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Giurgiu"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Gorj"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Harghita"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Hunedoara"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Ialomita"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Iasi"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Ilfov"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Maramures"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Mehedinti"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Mures"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Neamt"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Olt"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Prahova"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Salaj"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Satu Mare"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Sibiu"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Suceava"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Teleorman"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Timis"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Tulcea"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Valcea"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Vaslui"
    },
    {
        "nume": "Vrancea"
    }
]
```

I don't understand why is this happening.

.................................................

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not getting json in response. Try to add content-type: application/json header to your request.

```js
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
```

You can verify the response type of your request form the "Network Tab" in the chrome dev tool. You can learn more about chrome dev tools at [Chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Apparently it was because I had to provide the full path (http://localhost:port/api/getDropdownOptions) in the fetch call in fetchDropdownOptions function.